# Git/svn - keeping synced two repositories with different access rights

Tags: linux, svn, git

I've been advised by @PatrickQuirk to post this question here...

There is just too much information online for me to understand and be able to get my own picture, so I gently ask the community to provide light to my journey...

My situation:

we have a SVN server behind a firewall within our company. Impossible to move to DMZ.
we need some third party (our client) to access part of the source code from a remote location, since they are contributing to the development. BUT they are not from our company, so I cannot provide them VPN access. I need them to be able not only to read source, but also commit changes.
our SVN repo contains ALL our product. I want to give access to ONLY some folders to my client.
My company is VERY reluctant to let us buy a private GitHub account... for security reason, not cost...
We are trying for a few months the following, but it just doesn't work since it requires manual sync:

- rent a virtual machine online. Install a Git server. provide access to both our developers and our client.
- make an initial checkout of the reduced number of svn folders I want to share.
- We all work: either improving the code in these folders or creating new source code and folders.
- our developers are supposed to update/commits the two repos by hand... And this just does occur...

So I'm looking for solutions to automatically sync, but keeping in mind the access rights...

Another worry is that our company will during next year migrate all our SVN to Git... 
I have no issue in anticipating this and running our own git server instead of the SVN, but it will have to be kept behind the firewall. 
Then I'm lost with the "clone", "mirror" aspects and to maintain the correct access rights...

What solution/advice could you provide us in terms of this distributed architecture?

Comment: LOL. You are concerned about security and still consider moving to Git?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand your comment... if Git is behind a firewall, yes I expect it to be safe... Is there something in special I would worry about? Do you mean that Git is less safe than SVN? And what is your meaning of security? Also I've looking at SVN authz management by folder, and it seems Git only manages repository or branch access rights; not folders...